# How do I remove old stickers from my windshield?

Tags: windshield

There are some old stickers applied to my windshield and they won't peal off.
How do I remove these stickers and any adhesive residuals without damaging the windshield?

Comment: Related question on Travel.SE: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44770/how-can-i-remove-highway-vignettes-and-other-miscellaneous-stickers-from-the-win

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends very much on the sticker material. For vinyl stickers I've had good experience warming them up with a hairdryer to soften the glue and then slowly peeling them off. I've also managed to get them off a windshield using a scraper (essentially a razor blade with a handle similar to [this](http://www.harborfreight.com/razor-blade-scraper-98039.html)). You have to be a bit careful with the latter but I managed to get the vinyl sticker off without scratching the screen.

To remove the glue residue I've had good experience with both WD40 (which you can also use to soften paper stickers) and tar spot remover - I used Autoglym's tar remover but I'm sure you can get similar tar removers from a bunch of different brands.

Comment: In any case - it's better to remove from a warm surface than cold.

Comment: Those are good advice, but I wonder if there is a way to remove dealer warranty info glue marks on the inside of the car with tint (obviously, I cannot scrape as it will damage the tint).